# 'daprd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dapr

I am trying to debug a huge project using VS Code, the project is supposed to run on dapr using docker. I have installed dapr, docker, both seem to work fine. I also have VS Code, and I managed to get dapr extension for VS Code.

I build the project using dotnet build, no errors, so I am assuming that works fine, but when I try to debug it (run it) I get that error. I have read that it can be caused by  having to set up environmental variables, but I don't know which environmental variables, as they seem to be present in the path (c:\users\myself.dapr\bin) is present.

So I have a few questions: what should I do now? and what is the reason behind it? Basically, I want to fix this, but knowing and understanding how, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as restarting the laptop fix it, I guess that I did all of the installations without restarting and it needed a restart.

It was nothing to do with the environment variables in the end.